# RTOS: windows ce: can I perform all my calculations in kernel mode for a PID control loop?

Tags: c++, windows-ce, rtos

In Windows CE, can I do all my calucation for a PID(Proportional-Integral-Derivative) control loop in "kernel mode" and avoid using "user mode"? I will transfering data over TCP=IP to another machine for the end result to keep the system in "kernel mode".  My understanding is that switching from "kernel mode" to "user mode" and vice versa costs time..ie 40us round trip.

Comment: Kernel mode threads are subjected to thread scheduling just like user mode threads are.  The only possible advantage you might have is that you can push the thread priority so high that you can't be pre-empted.

Comment: @HansPassant In a previous question he asked something about real mode vs protected mode and that the fact that he would like to stay all the time in real mode, since he is reading data from a device.  In Windows CE, "kernel mode" threads have permission to access memory addresses outside of their own process. So this is his point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that, you should call SetKMode function to put your thread out or in of kernel mode. More details in these two blog posts from CE team: [What is Kernel Mode?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2007/01/29/what-is-kernel-mode.aspx) and [Inside Windows CE API Calls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2006/02/02/inside-windows-ce-api-calls.aspx).